# Insert custom boolean values in JSON python

Tags: python, json, boolean

I am creating a JSON using Python. It looks something like this:

```
[
...
{"name":"John","is_active":true}
...
]
```

This is like a configuration JSON that I will be passing to a config file.
How can I insert **true** as a value.

I do not want 'True' or **True**

I want to insert lowercase **true** as a value.

Comment: When you convert Python `True` it becomes JSON `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This automatically converts the `True` to `true` etc.

```py
import json

jsonlist = [
    {"test": True},
    {"test": False},
]

with open("test.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(jsonlist, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `json` module automatically maps the Python value `True` to the JSON value `true`:

For example,

```
>>> json.dumps({"name": "John", "is_active": True})
'{"name": "John", "is_active": true}'
```

The converse is also true: the JSON value `true` is parsed as the Python value `True`:

```
>>> json.loads('{"name": "John", "is_active": true}')
{'name': 'John', 'is_active': True}
```